# How can I store different values in a variable each time a loop iterates and then add them all together in c .?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct add_stock
{
    char name[30];
    int share;
    float price;
    float total;
} add_stock;

FILE *fp;
    add_stock *a;
    int n, i, j;
    printf("Hover the cursor on the URL and click (ctrl+click)  to know the d/b shares and stocks and then later on fill the further information as ask  https://youtu.be/AeEgoc3k_0o");
    printf("Enter the no. of stocks you have purchased : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    a = (add_stock *)calloc(n, sizeof(add_stock));
    fp = fopen("myportfolio.txt", "a");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i].total = 0;
        printf("Enter the name of the company : ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", a[i].name);

        printf("Enter how many shares you have bought : ");
        scanf("%d", &a[i].share);

        printf("Enter the price of each share : ");
        scanf("%f", &a[i].price);
        fprintf(fp, "\n%s \n%d \n%f", a[i].name, a[i].share, a[i].price);
        a[i].total += a[i].share * a[i].price;
        fprintf(fp, "\n%f", a[i].total);
    }
    
   
    fclose(fp);
```

what I want here is that ,I get the sum total of the total amount of money invested by a user. Currently,   it's giving me only the total amount of money invested in a specific company . But I also  want the total amount of money invested in all the companies .I hope u'll get my point.

For ex-
Company : tesla ,
No. of shares : 2,
Price of each share :  200.000000 ,
Total money  invested in the stock : 400.000000

Company : apple ,
No. of shares : 2 ,
Price of each share : 300.000000 ,
Total money invested in the stock : 600.000000

Now ,What I want => 400 + 600 = 1000.

Comment: Once you figure out the total amount invested in a company, just add that amount to a running total and then print...

Comment: You should include the definition of `add_stock ` in your question - for the data types needed to answer your question.  We can perhaps infer them from the `fprintf()` format specifiers, but we should not have to, and it is unsafe to assume you got that right in any case.

Comment: Really sorry for such an unclear explanation of question. I'm new here , but from now onwards I'll take care of that.

Comment: You have poor type agreement here.  `price` is a `float`, while `total` is `unsigned int`, and `share` is `int`.  Your totals will be rounded _down_ and your overall total will be in error significantly.  `total` at least needs to be a `float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ...

    float portfolio_total_value = 0.0f ; // <<<< Before your input loop
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ...

        a[i].total += a[i].share * a[i].price;
        portfolio_total_value += a[i].total ;   // <<<< Accumulate total in the input loop
        ...
    }
    
    // >>> Output the total *after* the input loop <<<<
    fprintf( fp, "\nPortfolio value: %f\n", portfolio_total_value ) ;
```

To get a correct solution however you also need to change:

```
unsigned int total;
```

to

```
float total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another variable

```
fp = fopen("myportfolio.txt", "a");
int grandTotal = 0;
```

then in the loop

```
    a[i].total += a[i].share * a[i].price;
    grandTotal += a[i].total;
    fprintf(fp, "\n%f", a[i].total);
```

Comment: @xguybluehat : The value you want is in `grandTotal` _after_ the loop.  You will have to be much clearer on the requirements if this is not a solution.  Perhaps by giving an example - in the question, not comments.  The example you have just given above is by no means clear either.  Nonetheless surely you can extrapolate from this answer - you simply accumulate whatever it is you need to accumulate in a variable as required.  Also you won't get an accurate answer without exhibiting the definition of `add_stock`

Comment: Since the `printf` call in the original code implies that `a[i].total` is a floating-point type, perhaps `grandTotal` should be also?  That said in a real-world financial application you would not use floating point perhaps, but let's assume that is not a real-world application perhaps.

Comment: I've a doubt , here u said portfolio_total_value += a[i].total ;   // <<<< Accumulate total in the input loop. It accumulates it but how does it adds it , I mean add all the a[i].total values.

Comment: @xguybluehat : You have applied your comment to this answer but referencing a different answer.  However this answer is more or less the same principle as mine.  The point being is that the accumulation is done _in the loop_.

Comment: accumulation is done in the loop , but how does it adds it?